# question about init and load from xib for a custom UIView

Tags: iphone

I am trying to create a custom UIView class which loads from a xim file that contains the interface for that view. I am trying to encapsulate the [NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed...] within the init method of my custom view as follows:

```
- (id)init 
{    
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoadingV" owner:self options:nil];
        self = [(LoadingV*)[nibViews objectAtIndex: 0] retain];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I want to know:

1. Is this an acceptable way of doing so? And is there any better way?
2. Should i keep the "retain" given that i do not call [self release] in dealloc?

Cheers
AF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not acceptable, it's bad practice and you actually have a memory leak there.

Better way to do this is to use a pattern called "factory".

Example:

```
@interface CustomView: UIView
@end

@implementation CustomView
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // custom view loaded from nib
}
@end

@interface UIView (Nib)
+ (UIView *)viewFromNib:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)bundle;
@end

@implementation UIView (Nib)
+ (UIView *)viewFromNib:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)bundle {
    if (!nibName || [nibName length] == 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    UIView *view = nil;

    if (!bundle) {
        bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    }

    // I assume, that there is only one root view in interface file
    NSArray *loadedObjects = [bundle loadNibNamed:nibName owner:nil options:nil];
    view = [loadedObjects lastObject];

    return view;
}
@end
```

Usage:

```
// CustomView.xib contains one View object with its class set to "CustomView"
CustomView *myView = (CustomView *)[UIView viewFromNib:@"CustomView" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: thanks for the response. The logic ur using in ur factory function is almost similar to the one i have (only if i remove the retain). But ur function is a Class method which doe not associate to self. What should i do if i need to have an object of my custom view that calls other member functions?

Comment: UIView has `awakeFromNib` method where you can customize it.

Comment: awakeFromNib is not useful for me as i am trying to load the custom view from xin. that call would not have been called yet!

Comment: Created XIB file, put View object in that file, select it and set its class to your custom class. That would be exactly what you want.

Comment: I am already doing that. The issue is when i want to instantiate that custom view and load its xib file. that what i am trying to achieve. The code above does it but just wanted to know if there is any better way

Comment: Sorry did not notice your commit earlier. That makes sense to me now. But i am still not sure why i never encountered any memory leak whatsoever with my implementation and even XCode Build and Analyse never detected that as a memory leak?!! I will adopt your solution any ways

Comment: Static analyzer isn't perfect. You see, you allocate memory for object and then rewrite reference to it with reference to another object. So your first object will never be released because you don't have any valid references to it.