# Retain count and factory methods in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have been in this forum before to find the best way of creating a factory function to construct a custom view from a nib ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191959/question-about-init-and-load-from-xib-for-a-custom-uiview) is my previous post)

i am now using the following code:

```
+ (LoadingV *)loadingViewCopyFromNib 
{   
    LoadingV *view = nil;   
    NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoadingV" owner:self options:nil];
    view = (LoadingV*)[nibViews objectAtIndex: 0];

    // Setting up properties
    CGRect frm = view.progress.frame;
    frm.size.width *=1.5;
    frm.size.height *=1.5;
    view.progress.frame = frm;
    view.waitLbl.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Please wait", @"");     
    return view;    <------- warning is here
}

// In .h file
...
LoadingView* loadV;
@property (nonatomic, retain) LoadingView* loadV;

// in .m file
@synthesize loadV;
...
self.loadV = [LoadingV loadingViewCopyFromNib];
```

When i Build and Analyse i get the following warning about the factory function:

> /LPAPP/Classes/LoadingV.m:34:5 Object with +0 retain counts returned
>   to caller where a +1 (owning) retain count is expected

Why is this happening? I understand that local variables allocated within a function do not live beyond its scope unless they are retained and autoreleased. But in my case i am not creating a new object am just returning a reference to an existing one. So why am i getting warning back? Is it safe to proceed like this :)

Cheers
AF

Comment: Apparently the analyzer counts "loading" among the prefixes (init, copy, et al) that will be returning a retained object.

Comment: I think you are right on this! will change the API name and remove Copy. The implementation was different in the past then  modified it without paying attention to the naming convention. cheers

Comment: Which version of XCode are you using?.. clang/llvm 3.0 (iOS 5 beta) will have a different naming convention processing built in for ARC/ARC transition and maybe it's a little buggy

Comment: I am not using XCode 4 as i had terrible experience when i installed it. I am back to XCode 3.2.5 with SDK 4.3.3 (or 4.3.1 not sure :p)

Comment: I just tested changing the name of the function and remove Copy and it all worked. Not warnings anymore! Cheers guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Mike is right, the warning has a completely different reason.
Your method name includes "copy" which is interpreted to return a +1 retain count (similar to alloc, init). Remember that once you transition to ARC this may cause problems!

Comment: This is incorrect, only a *prefix* of 'copy' or 'mutableCopy' it interpreted as a +1 retain count.

Comment: yeah apple likes to document some "features" more than others... analyzer seems to work a little different..

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to collection classes like `NSArray`, references returned by `objectAtIndex:` and other similar accessors are not guaranteed to stay valid when the parent container is deallocated. In other words, `objectAtIndex:` does not return an autorelease'd object.

This means the pointer you return will probably end up becoming invalid once the array it came from is deallocated.

To fix this, use a `retain`+`autorelease` in your return statement:

```
return [[view retain] autorelease];
```

**UPDATE:**

I'm unable to reproduce this warning in my version of Xcode. But perhaps Martin is correct that the 'copy' is being interpreted incorrectly by the version of GCC/clang that you are using. This warning doesn't appear with the latest Xcode and gcc/clang compilers, and the rules are that only a *prefix* of "copy" or "mutableCopy" is interpreted as returning a +1 retained object.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right, though of course the analyzer is wrong -- the returned object is "good" until the next autorelease already, unless Objective-C is changed to recognize that nibViews has passed out of scope.

Comment: The analyzer isn't wrong. Yes, the implementation details today are such that the object will remain valid, but the analyzer deals simply with object ownership rules which the code violates. If some underlying implementations change in the future, your original code could conceivably stop working.

Comment: The implementation could always change in the future, to break this without changing any of the above code.  But of course such a change would break lots of apps (not that Apple is above breaking lots of apps with their changes).

Comment: Incidentally, which line exactly is the static analyzer complaining about? I'm having trouble reproducing this analyzer warning.

Comment: I think the object returned from objectAtIndex will remain alive until next autorelease since it is a reference for an object already in an array that is autoreleased (nibViews). And calling self.loadV =... will even keep it alive longer. That was the reason why i was not sure about the warning and thought of asking. I will change the name of the function and remove Copy as i think  Daniel R Hicks has a point

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using? The release version should not be showing a warning for this method. 'copy' only has meaning as a method prefix.