# Loading a custom UIView from xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, xib

I have a custom `UIView` which I am loading in this manner

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withDelegate:(id)del
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    UIView *myView;

    if (self)
    {
        NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class])
                                                      owner:self
                                                    options:nil];
        for (id object in nibViews) 
        {
            if ([object isKindOfClass:[self class]])
            myView = object;
        }

        myView.frame = frame;
        myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [self addSubview: myView];
    }

    self.delegate = del;
    return self;
}
```

On loading the view like this when UIView method returns `self` all the outlets linked in the `Interface Builder` are `nil`. Is it not the right way ?

Comment: You don't need `for-loop` just use `myView = [nibViews firstObject];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a xib file in a UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814928/how-to-load-a-xib-file-in-a-uiview)

Comment: Please do share demo code if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [question about init and load from xib for a custom UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191959/question-about-init-and-load-from-xib-for-a-custom-uiview)

Answer (score 0):

Use this method for load particular xib from bundle

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class])
                                              owner:self
                                            options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
myView =[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(self.class) owner:self options:nil].firstObject];
```

Or simple you can use

```
myView = [nibViews firstObject]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you provide IBOutlet in the xid and when you try to load the view like you provide these values is nil. This is anticipated becouse you create onew viwe and add the view from xib as subview. So the parrent view does not set this values.
to fixe this you need to rework method as loaded your view.
Please try use this:

```
+ (id)createWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withDelegate:(id)del
{


    NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class])
                                                      owner:nil
                                                    options:nil];
    <Provide class name> *myView = nibViews[0];
    myView.frame = frame;
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    myView.delegate = del;
    return myView;
}
```